# node app on port 3000 displays a listing directory instead of rendering the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am running Windows 7, tried in Opera and Chrome.

The weird thing is, sometimes it works sometimes in just displays a blank page with a directories listing.

Here is the code, the callback in app.listen works only in the CLI, not in the browsers dev tools.

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var path = require("path");

var app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var person = {
name: "test",
age: 444
}

app.get("/", function(req, res){
res.json(person);
res.send("connected to port 3000");
});


app.listen(3000,'127.0.0.1', function(){
console.log("connected to port 3000");

});
```

I am using nodemon, and I am not sure it this is the root issue.

What is wrong here, the odd thing is, it works sometimes.Then I do some changes at random places in the files and I get the directory listing.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all unneeded stuff and see if your port is open first

```
var express = require("express")

var app = express()


app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.send("hello world")
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(`Express is running on port ${port}`)
})
```

See if your console is returning the correct port first, then go to browser and key in `localhost:3000`. If the connection works you should see hello world.

Also, in package.json, are you running the `app.js` file using

`"scripts" : {"start": "nodemon app"}` ?

Comment: Thanks, but still the same, the command line returns running on port 3000, 

I have had install nodemon -g, now I will save it as dependency. (does not work, I get error messages installing nodemon now) .However, even running it as node app.js would be the same.

Now, when I comment out all the other code and leaver only yours in, it seems to work. An then, a minute later, it stops working again.

Comment: Something is definitely wrong here, it just worked, then I just changed the the string in the person object just slightly, to test, and then I get the directory listing again..Nodemon works now.
Look like it is the body-parser or path causing trouble.